# Parsing an XML document

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, tags

I want to parse an XML document in c++ and be able to identify what text exists in a particular tag. I have checked parsers like TiyXML and PugiXML but none of them seem to identify the tags separately. How can I achieved this?

Comment: Writing an XML parser is not an easy task.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Please elaborate more on the task, what would you like to achive? When parsing xml file, you need to know the scheme with all possible attributes. What is missing in available xml parsers?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you showed some sample XML (with text), and say what you want to extract.  Note that given `<tag1>abc<tag2>def</tag2>pqr</tag1>` all parsers will allow you to get 'abc' and `pqr'.

Comment: I wish to get 'tag1' and 'tag2'. How can it be done in PugiXML?

Answer (score 0):

Using [RapidXml](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/), you can traverse the nodes and attributes and identify the text of their tag.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <rapidxml.hpp>
#include <rapidxml_utils.hpp>
#include <rapidxml_iterators.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace rapidxml;

    file<> in ("input.xml"); // Load the file in memory.
    xml_document<> doc;
    doc.parse<0>(in.data()); // Parse the file.

    // Traversing the first-level elements.
    for (node_iterator<> first=&doc, last=0; first!=last; ++first)
    {
        std::cout << first->name() << '\n'; // Write tag.

        // Travesing the attributes of the element.
        for (attribute_iterator<> attr_first=*first, attr_last=0;
                attr_first!=attr_last; ++attr_first)
        {
            std::cout << attr_first->name() << '\n'; // Write tag.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all tag names with [pugixml](http://pugixml.org):

```
void dumpTags(const pugi::xml_node& node) {
  if (!node.empty()) {
    std::cout << node.name() << std::endl;
    for (pugi::xml_node child=node.first_child(); child; child=child.next_sibling())
      dumpTags(child);
  }
}

pugi::xml_document doc;
pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load("<tag1>abc<tag2>def</tag2>pqr</tag1>");
dumpTags(doc.first_child());
```